# python + nginx internal server error

Tags: python, python-3.x, nginx, vagrant, uwsgi

So I've setup my server following this tutorial: http://jronnholm.sysio.se/setup-nginx-and-uwsgi-with-python3-on-ubuntu-14-04/

See: [nginx + uwsgi + python3 configuration not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42101845/nginx-uwsgi-python3-configuration-not-working)

I managed to get it to work by switching `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` with `/etc/nginx/sites-available/pythonapp` and change the sitename to `_`.

My `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`:

```
server {
    server_name _;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/pythonapp.error.log;
    access_log         /var/log/nginx/pythonapp.access.log;
    root /vagrant/site/python/pythonapp;
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass unix:/var/run/uwsgi/app/pythonapp/socket;
        include uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

But then when I change the content of `webpage.py` to this:

```
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print("lololol");
```

It ends up returning internal server error when I go to http://localhost:8080.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python code of your `webpage.py` is invalid. Try running it directly from the command line: `python3 webpage.py` will show you what is wrong.

Change your `webpage.py` to:

```
print("Content-type: text/html\n\n")
print("lololol")
```

The print statement has been replaced with a `print()` function, with keyword arguments to replace most of the special syntax of the old print statement ([PEP 3105](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/)).

Note I've removed the semicolon from the second line because it is not doing anything in your example. Python does not require semi-colons to terminate statements. Semicolons can be used to delimit statements if you wish to put multiple statements on the same line.